# Performance impact in reading a collection from MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

Atomicity is at document level in MongoDB, but not collection level

---

Backend application one is connecting to MongoDB and updating the collection(`c1`), very frequently

Backend application two is connecting to MongoDB and reading the collection(`c1`), less frequently.

---

collections does not have indexes

We see response lag from backend application two, in retrieving data of collection(`c1`)

What is the performance impact on reading MongoDB collection(`c1`)? when DB user1 updates the same collection(`c1`) that is read by DB user2.

Comment: It depends on many details not present in your question. Does the collection have indexes that are affected by the write operations? Are transactions being used? What is the majority and how far apart (delay) are the replicas? What are the filters being used? Have you analyzed the results from `explain()`? In general, when one process is writing to a collection, another process must wait for those writes to complete. That is an oversimplification but a conservative way to view database activity. If you write a lot, the database will be slower.

Comment: @JohnHanley There are no replicas. We just hosted mongodb as kubernetes pod. So, there are no replicas. There are no indexes on collection.